# Scalate TemplateException with Play 2.2.1

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, scalate

I'm trying to use Scalate 1.6.1 with Play, but it gives me this:

```
[TemplateException: scala.reflect.internal.TreeInfo.firstArgument(Lscala/reflect/internal/Trees$Tree;)Lscala/reflect/internal/Trees$Tree;]
```

in this code in the ScalaIntegration.scala

```
def render(args: (Symbol, Any)*) = {
  ScalateContent{
    scalateEngine.layout(name, args.map {
      case (k, v) => k.name -> v
    } toMap)
  }
}
```

I know it can be a version problem, so I'm currently trying to run it with scala 2.10.0, but I would like then to change to 2.10.2 .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the scala version, try specifying the dependency versions for scala-reflect and scala-compiler explicitly by adding this in your sbt build.scala: (In my case I wanted to use 2.10.3)

```
libraryDependencies ++= seq(
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.10.3",
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.10.3"
)
```

This is based on Ross A. Baker's response here:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalate/rKNkwgHPQDM/ClfBTM1VyegJ

Answer (score 0):

Scalate 1.6.1 depends on scala-reflect functions that are missing in 2.10.3.
Try Scalate 1.7.0 from the scalatra folks:

```
"org.scalatra.scalate" % "scalate-something" % "1.7.0"
```

Anyways, Scalate does't seem to be maintained well by the fusesource folks:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalate/X_EcZEUk_lo